# How can I increse 12V and 0.5A DC to 200V DC?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, step-up

I am very new in electrical circuits and I need help to create a circuit which would create from 12V and max 0.5A input, output with 200V and some small current. Consequently, I need to regulate this voltage in scale 0-200V for supplying a piezoelectric load.

I would like to ask:

- What should I use for this type of increasing voltage (if you made something similar what have you used)? I chacked step-up convertor and found this one: https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt8331.html#product-overview
  In datasheet has this device maximal switching voltage 140V. But later in a datasheet is one schematics which shows how to get 240V and 15mA from input 10V to 48V. So the switching voltage makes some limitation for the output voltage from the step-up circuit? Actually, would it be the solution to my issue?

[image]

- How can I regulate continuously this voltage in range 0-200V? I thought about using some MOSFET or JFET. But when the voltage is so high and current is so small (i am assuming that I would use the step-up above with output 15mA) is it possible to regulate the voltage continuously with some FET? If not how can I control the voltage, Should I use something else or should I increase the current?

Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Have you considered that 12 V * 0.5 A = 6 W = 200 V * 30 mA = potentially lethal? And if I understand you correctly, that is just nominal, peak values might be much higher and therefore even more deadly.

Comment: Do you really need to be able to adjust down to 0? With a boost converter you can't get the output to be less than the input voltage. You'll either need to play tricks with what you call "ground" on each side of the circuit, or use a different topology.

Comment: Also, how quickly do you need to vary the output? Are you just using the piezo as a slowly moving precision displacement device, or are you trying to produce audio or ultrasound vibrations?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have output ranging from -100 to +100 V instead of 0 to 200 V?

Comment: I would like to control a piezoelectric actuator and the frequency of creating the input into the actuator should be around 60Hz. Yes, output values could be also in range -100 to +100 V, actually, it could be even better than 0 to 200V.